# Thymeleaf Preselected Select2 Options

Tags: java, jquery-select2, thymeleaf

I'm trying to render an edit page that has a multi-select list using select2. According to the select2 docs, simply setting an option `selected="selected"` should work, but I'm using Java/Spring and Thymeleaf templating so it's a bit tricky.

```
<select id="programs" name="programs.id" style="min-width: 200px;" multiple="multiple">
    <option
            th:each="programs : ${programs}"
            th:value="${programs.id}"
            th:text="'['+${programs.category.name}+'] '+${programs.name}"
            th:selected="${#lists.contains(personProg,programs.id)}">
    </option>
</select>
```

`programs.id` is the id of the program, and `personProg` is a list of programs associated to a persons id, thus, pre-selected on the list.

This compiles and loads fine, but doesn't have any options selected. No html or anything and I've looked at several questions noting the `#lists.contains()` method. I saw that it doesn't work with `th:field` attributes, but I don't have that either.

Java for reference:

```
@RequestMapping(value="edit", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String Edit(Model model, @RequestParam(value="userID") long id) {
    Person person = repo.findById(id);
    model.addAttribute("person", person);
    model.addAttribute("users", repo.findByOrderByLastnameAsc());
    model.addAttribute("programs", progRepo.findByOrderByIdAsc());
    model.addAttribute("personProg", personProgRepo.findByPersonid(person.getID()));
    for (PersonPrograms x : personProgRepo.findByPersonid(person.getID())) {
        System.out.println(x.getProgramid());
    }
    return "edit";
}
```

Outputs in the java console:

```
69
1
2
3
66
6
37
59
58
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model attribute being sent over is a `personProg` list, not a list of the IDs you wanted. Make a list, and send over the list of IDs instead of the list of objects.

```
List<Integer> programIdList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (PersonPrograms x : personProgRepo.findByPersonid(person.getID())) {
   programIdList.add(x.getProgramid());
}
model.addAttribute("personProg", programIdList.toString());
```